# Can one design an asymmetric encryption scheme based on any secret sharing scheme? Are they that closely related?

Tags: encryption, public-key

I've seen both asymmetric encryption and secret sharing schemes based on graph 3-coloring, and I'm curious if this is a coincidence due to some peculiar property of graph 3-coloring alone.

Comment: could you provide the two articles about the 3-colouring based work?

Comment: [Page 238](https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/crypto/download/file.php?id=3026107) of **Discrete Mathematics Using Latin Squares** describes a public-key system based on Latin Squares (which I believe are a form of the 3-coloring problem).  The [previous page](https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/crypto/download/file.php?id=3026106) describes a secret-sharing scheme using Latin Squares.  Also, [this](https://ro.uow.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=2112&context=infopapers) paper.  [This](https://arxiv.org/ftp/cs/papers/0310/0310053.pdf) paper also.

Comment: @Meler_Lawer, Latin Square = n coloring, if n =3 the 3-coloring? My answer has mistakes. deleting. could you write one? I like to see.

Comment: I think the answer is yes.  **EDIT:** I don't understand, what do you want me to write?

Comment: I've looked for RSA based secret sharing but couldn't one. Also, I couldn't find about asymmetric encryption scheme based on 3-coloring.

Comment: an answer to your question

Comment: I don't know if the answer to my question is yes or no, so I can't answer it myself. Sorry.  But if you click the first link in my first comment, the 2nd paragraph describes the asymmetric encryption scheme based on 3-coloring (it doesn't use the word 3-coloring, but Latin Squares are a form of 3-coloring).